# meteor creates symbolic link to wrong computer

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I moved my app to another Ubuntu computer. As soon as I launch the app with `meteor` or `meteor run` on the new computer, it errors out with:

> EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, unlink
>   '/home/hoosiercoder/dev/simple-todos/.meteor/local/dev_bundle'

I checked that directory, I do have symbolic links to an old version of meteor from my old computer. I think that's what generates the error.

The problem is that when I remove all the symbolic links, and try to run the app again, meteor just creates another symbolic link.. again to the old version of meteor. :(

How do I work around this problem and get the app running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I created a new meteor test app on the new machine
2. Reinstalled all the libraries
3. Replaced the .meteor folder in the original app with the new .meteor folder from the test app

This solved the problem on the new box.